# matlab: reading numbers that also contain characters

Tags: matlab

I have to read a textfile which contains a list of companycodes. The format of the textfile is:

[1233A12; 1233B88; 2342Q85; 2266738]

Even if I have read the file? Is it possible to compare these numbers with regular numbers? Because I have the codes from two different data-bases and one of them has regular firmnumbers (no characters) and the other has characters inside the firmnumbers.

Btw the file is big (50+mb).

Edit: I have added an additional number in the example because not all the numbers have a character inside

Comment: I wouldn't use MATLAB for such a problem. I recommend preprocessing with Python. Use hash tables.

Comment: I dont have any experience with python. Do you think its posible with C++

Comment: Sure. But if you have the capability of learning C++, learning python to do this should take at most a day. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this result by using regular expressions. For example, if `str = '1233A12'` you can write

```
nums = regexp(str, '(\d+)[A-Z]*(\d+)', 'tokens');
str1 = nums{1}(1);
num1 = str2num(str1{1});
str2 = nums{1}(2);
num2 = str2num(str2{1});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare part of a string with a number, you could do it as follows:

```
combiString = '1234AB56'
myNumber= 1234 

str2num(combiString(1:4))==myNumber
str2num(combiString(7:8))==myNumber
```